# Using lambda expressions in a query

Tags: c#, linq, azure, lambda

I am running this query on a Windows Azure Web Role, and need to get a related entity set, but my lambda expression doesn't seem to be working.

```
 var query = from p in applicationsContext.Programs.Expand(p => p.Campus)
                    where p.ProgramId == Int32.Parse(programsList.SelectedValue)
                    select p;
```

I am using `System.Linq` and`System.Data.Entities` already, but the lambda expression `(p => p.Campus)` causes the error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type

Any idea as to why this wouldn't work?

EDIT: Intellisence also doesn't seem to recognize the 'p' in the lambda expression, that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Expand expects a sting, not a delegate. Maybe just `"Campus" ` would work?

Comment: Can you share the tutorial you're working with??

Answer (score 2):

I think `Expand` must get string parameter ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc679728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Then you can't use delegate instead string.

Comment: Agree, that's the reason.

Comment: So what would be the fix? What sort of link would I be putting in?

Comment: If `Campus` is `int`, you don't need `Expand` this property. If `Campus` is related entity, then use `Expand("Campus")`

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess: is `p.Campus` something other than string type?

Comment: p.Campus is an int, but judging from the example I'm working off of that shouldn't effect it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what data source you're going against, but do not re-use the same 'p' for the inner Expand statement:

```
 var query = from p in applicationsContext.Programs.Expand(t => t.Campus)
                    where p.ProgramId == Int32.Parse(programsList.SelectedValue)
                    select p;
```